# Open Auction again after succesful transaction - Why?

Tags: ens, name-registrar

I'm using MetaMask for bidding via the ENS registrar DApp. It happens from time to time that the transaction for a bid is confirmed on etherscan, and also the .json file lists it NOT as pending. But the registrar page shows "You have bid but ..." -> "Open Auction", and the ENS lookup doesn't show any actions on the name. Does anyone know why this happens (quite often BTW)?

Comment: I have heard reports of some flakiness in the registrar dapp. You may have more luck with myetherwallet. Successful bids will not show up in etherscan because it is a secret auction. You can only see the auction start events, reveals, and finalizes.

Comment: Thank you, @carver. Is there a chance that the "flakiness" will be transformed into more "solid condition" in the future?

Comment: I don't think there's a ton of active work on it right now. It seems likely that more work will go into it before the next big launch in two years. My suggestion would be to use a different interface if you're having problems, like myetherwallet.com. Or a command line tool, if you're into that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I made a video about using MetaMask for bidding via the ENS registrar DApp. 
It shows how I dealt with the flakiness, having to Open an Auction that failed to open even though you did Bid on it, etc.
https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=jyzorDfro8U

Comment: Hi! Link doesn't work for me.